# Problems with Node Extension

Tags: c++, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to make a Node extension per...

http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world

With a couple minor modifications (mine is called helloworld.cc and testnode.js) but when I try to compile the following line...

```
require('./build/Release/helloworld');
```

I get the following ST

```
node.js:242
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: invalid argument
at Object..node (module.js:475:11)
at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
at Function._load (module.js:309:12)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jackie/Desktop/hellonode/testnode.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
at Function._load (module.js:309:12)
```

an ls of the release directory is ...

total 124
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackie jackie 70288 2012-04-07 16:16 helloworld_1.o
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jackie jackie 49431 2012-04-07 16:16 helloworld.node

Thanks

Jackie

Comment: If you're going to downvote a question, it seems only polite to add a comment explaining what the asker could do better, or else you risk chasing them off.

Comment: Did you change the `NODE_MODULE(hello, init)` line to `NODE_MODULE(helloworld, init)`? Could you post the C++ code?

Comment: Loganfsmyth seems to have been right it was a problem in my CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the `.node` file needs to match the name in the `NODE_MODULE` macro.

```
NODE_MODULE(hello, init);
```

needs to be changed to

```
NODE_MODULE(helloworld, init);
```